# two writes()(has sleep() between them) to socket

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I'm practicing echo server/client, and has something problem.

This is the header file name `myheader.h`

```
  #include <arpa/inet.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <errno.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <signal.h>

  typedef void Sigfunc(int);

  static int read_cnt;
  static char *read_ptr;
 static char read_buf[1024];

 ssize_t
 readn(int fd, void *vptr, size_t n)
 {
          size_t nleft;
         ssize_t nread;
         char *ptr;

          ptr=vptr;
          nleft=n;

          while(nleft>0)
          {
                  if((nread=read(fd, ptr, nleft))<0)
                  {
                          if(errno==EINTR)
                                  nread=0;
                          else
                                  return -1;
                  }
                  else if(nread==0)
                          break;          /* End of File reached */

                  nleft-=nread;
                  ptr+=nread;
          }
          return (n-nleft);
  }

  ssize_t
  writen(int fd, const void *vptr, size_t n)
  {
          size_t nleft;
          ssize_t nwritten;
          const char *ptr;

          ptr=vptr;
          nleft=n;

          while(nleft>0)
          {
                  if((nwritten=write(fd, ptr, nleft))<=0)
                  {
                          if(nwritten<0 && errno==EINTR)
                                  nwritten=0;     /* and call write() again */
                          else
                                  return -1;      /* error */
                  }

                  nleft-=nwritten;
                  ptr+=nwritten;
          }

          return n;
  }

  static ssize_t
  my_read(int fd, char *ptr)
  {
          if(read_cnt<=0)
          {
                  again:
                          if((read_cnt=read(fd, read_buf, sizeof(read_buf)))<0)
                          {
                                  if(errno==EINTR)
                                          goto again;
                                  return -1;
                          }
                          else if(read_cnt==0)
                                  return 0;
                          read_ptr=read_buf;
          }

          read_cnt--;

          *ptr=*read_ptr++;
          return 1;
  }

  ssize_t
  Readline(int fd, void *vptr, size_t maxlen)
  {
          ssize_t n, rc;
          char    c, *ptr;
          ptr=vptr;

         for(n=1; n<maxlen; n++)
         {
                 if((rc=my_read(fd, &c))==1)
                 {
                         *ptr++=c;
                         if(c=='\n')
                                 break;
                 }
                 else if(rc==0)
                 {
                         *ptr=0;
                         return (n-1);
                 }
                 else
                         return -1;
         }

         *ptr=0;
         return n;
 }

 void
 str_echo(int sockfd)
 {
         ssize_t n;

         char    buf[1024];

         again:
                 while((n=read(sockfd, buf, 1024))>0)
                         writen(sockfd, buf, n);

                 if(n<0 && errno==EINTR)
                         goto again;
                 else if(n<0)
                 {
                         printf("str_echo: read error");
                         exit(1);
                 }
 }

 void
 str_cli(FILE *fp, int sockfd)
 {
         char    sendline[1024], recvline[1024];

         while(fgets(sendline, 1024, fp)!=NULL)
         {
                 //writen(sockfd, sendline, strlen(sendline));

                 writen(sockfd, sendline, 1);
                 sleep(1000);
                 writen(sockfd, sendline+1, strlen(sendline)-1);
                 if(Readline(sockfd, recvline, 1024)==0)
                 {
                         printf("str_cli: server terminated prematurely");
                 }

                 fputs(recvline, stdout);
         }
 }


 Sigfunc*
 Signal(int signo, Sigfunc *func)
 {
         struct sigaction act, oact;

         act.sa_handler=func;
         sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
         act.sa_flags=0;

         if(signo==SIGALRM)
         {
 #ifdef SA_INTERRUPT
                 act.sa_flags |=SA_INTERRUPT;
 #endif
         }
         else
         {
 #ifdef SA_RESTART
                 act.sa_flags |=SA_RESTART;
 #endif
         }

         if(sigaction(signo, &act, &oact)<0)
                 return SIG_ERR;

         return oact.sa_handler;
 }
```

This is the echo client source code:

```
       #include "myheader.h"
       #include <sys/socket.h>
       #include <netinet/in.h>

       int
       main(int argc, char** argv)
       {
               struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
               int sockfd;

              sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, 0);

              bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

              servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
              servaddr.sin_port=htons(9877);
              inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &servaddr.sin_addr);

              connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

              str_cli(stdin, sockfd);

              exit(0);
      }
```

This is the echo server code:

```
   #include "myheader.h"
   #include <signal.h>

   void
   sig_chld(int signo)
   {
           pid_t   pid;
           int     status;

          while((pid=waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG))>0)
                  printf("child %d terminated\n", pid);

          return;
  }

  int
  main(int argc, char** argv)
  {
          int     listenfd, connfd;
          pid_t   childpid;
          socklen_t       clilen;
          struct sockaddr_in cliaddr, servaddr;

          listenfd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

          bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

          servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
          servaddr.sin_port=htons(9877);
          servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);

          bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

          listen(listenfd, 5);

          signal(SIGCHLD, sig_chld);

          for(;;)
          {
                  clilen=sizeof(cliaddr);
                  if((connfd=accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr, &clilen))<0)
                  {
                          if(errno=EINTR)
                                  continue;
                          else
                          {
                                  printf("accpet error\n");
                                  exit(1);
                          }
                  }

                  if((childpid=fork())==0)
                  {
                          close(listenfd);
                          str_echo(connfd);
                          exit(0);
                  }
                  close(connfd);
          }
  }
```

So when I connect to echo server, I type message like 'hello guys'
then, it should send data to server `1` bytes first, which is `h` here.

and then it sleeps 10 seconds. and then `ello guys` should be sent.

But, when I type 'hello guys'. I got the 'hello guys' from server immediately. Why I got full messages immediately,not divided?

This is the TCPDUMP what I received: (I send the `hello`)

```
21:17:27.798745 IP localhost.47761 > localhost.9877: Flags [S], seq 319562030, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 1147465 ecr 0,nop,wscale 10], length 0
21:17:27.798762 IP localhost.9877 > localhost.47761: Flags [S.], seq 3488701479, ack 319562031, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 1147465 ecr 1147465,nop,wscale 10], length 0
21:17:27.798779 IP localhost.47761 > localhost.9877: Flags [.], ack 1, win 43, options [nop,nop,TS val 1147465 ecr 1147465], length 0
21:17:58.130012 IP localhost.47761 > localhost.9877: Flags [P.], seq 1:7, ack 1, win 43, options [nop,nop,TS val 1155048 ecr 1147465], length 6
21:17:58.130065 IP localhost.9877 > localhost.47761: Flags [.], ack 7, win 43, options [nop,nop,TS val 1155048 ecr 1155048], length 0
21:17:58.130093 IP localhost.9877 > localhost.47761: Flags [P.], seq 1:7, ack 7, win 43, options [nop,nop,TS val 1155048 ecr 1155048], length 6
21:17:58.130114 IP localhost.47761 > localhost.9877: Flags [.], ack 7, win 43, options [nop,nop,TS val 1155048 ecr 1155048], length 0
```

Comment: What is readline() supposed to do?

Comment: It receives the same data which is sent from client from server. (It means echo). It is just line reading. when server receives data from client, then it sends the data to client with '\n' . And `fp` is `stdin` here

Comment: sleep(10) is a 10ms delay?

Comment: What is writen() supposed to do?

Comment: `readline()` is a library function. Either your program calls it with the wrong argument types , or you managed to reuse its name.

Comment: Well. 'if(n<0)....;else if(n<0)' does not fill me with confidence:(

Comment: I detect three different styles.

Comment: BTW: this could be a case of interrupted sleep. print the return value you get from sleep().

Comment: Please edit your code such that it is all in one place, ready for the copy/paste/compile/run cycle.

Comment: I edit my contents. And I put the `printf("sleep() time: %d \n", a);` right after `a=sleep(10)`. But it doesn't show me the result of  `sleep() time: %d`